# Using External Function in NuSOAP with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am new to code with NuSOAP lib. Currently, I've just accomplished connected client with server and get service.

Right now, my service or function is on the same php file as soap server. I register my function that on the same page using this code :

```
$server->register("myFunction");
```

how can I register a function if I have external php file that consist my function that I needed ?

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to include your php file in your code, and before, register the method or function.

Be sure if your function need to parameters or has a return. In that case, you must inscribe your parametes and return statements using the method register of the webservice.

See here http://www.wackylabs.net/2004/07/creating-a-web-service-and-wsdl-using-nusoap/

In that example, when you see **`&gt`** replace by **`>`**